# running jasmine with grunt

Tags: gruntjs, jasmine, grunt-contrib-jasmine

I am trying to run jasmine tests with grunt however I am getting this error message and I am not sure where to go next with resolving it. Here is the actual error message when I try to run jasmine with grunt

```
$ grunt jasmine:all
Loading "jasmine.js" tasks...ERROR
>> TypeError: Cannot read property '_' of undefined
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> TypeError: Cannot read property '_' of undefined
Warning: Cannot read property 'namespace' of undefined Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
Fatal error: Cannot read property 'exit' of undefined
/Users/user1/dev/app/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/fail.js:57
  grunt.util.exit(typeof errcode === 'number' ? errcode : fail.code.FATAL_ERROR);
            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'exit' of undefined
    at Object.fail.fatal (/Users/user1/dev/app/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/fail.js:57:13)
    at process.uncaughtHandler (/Users/user1/dev/app/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt.js:130:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at process.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at process._fatalException (node.js:234:26)
```

Where do I go next with trying to figure this one out?

added gruntfile

module.exports = function(grunt) {

```
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    //all configuration goes here
    jshint: {
        options: {
            reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
        },
        build: ['Gruntfile.js','src/**/*.js']
    },

    uglify: {
        options: {
            banner: '/*\n <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> \n */\n'
        },
        build: {
            files: {
            'dist/js/bundle.min.js' : 
                 [
                  'bower_components/angular/angular.js'
                 ]
            }

        }
    },

    less: {
        build: {
            files: {
            'dist/css/pretty.css' : 
                 [
                  'src/css/pretty.less'
                 ]
            }
        }
    },

    cssmin: {
        options: {
            banner: '/*\n <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> \n */\n'
        },
        build: {
            files: {
            'dist/css/style.min.css' :
                 [
                  'src/css/style.css'
                 ]
            }
        }
    },

    watch: {
        stylesheets: {
            files: ['src/**/*.css', 'src/**/*.less'],
            tasks: ['less', 'cssmin']
        },
        scripts: {
            files: 'src/**/*.js',
            tasks: ['jshint', 'uglify']
        }
    }
});


//loads grunt plugins
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jasmine');


grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint', 'uglify', 'cssmin', 'less']); 
};
```

Comment: Post your Gruntfile.js

Comment: Not seeing your `jasmine` task in `Gruntfile`